# Execute python at visual code but fail (error message: python path configuration.....)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I execute the python at visual code, the error happen. Message like below:

[image]

I did the solutions like add PYTHONPATH and turn off python related exe at Manage app executions aliases.

Thanks!

Comment: Add python to PATH in system variables first

Answer (score 0):

I THINK THAT YOU HAVE NOT CREATED A PATH OF VS CODE IN ENVIRONMENTAL VARIABLES.
IF ITS DONE ONLY YOU CAN EXECUTE PROGRAMS IN VS CODE.
ELSE YOU HAVE TO DOWNLOAD LATEST VERSION OF PYTHON (3.9.6).

Answer (score 0):

This is my `sys.path`:

```
['d:\\workPlace\\pythontest3.9\\hello',
 'D:\\workPlace\\pythontest3.9',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages']
```

It is a little weird because I really can't make my `sys.path` contains `.\\DLLs` and
`\\lib` instead of the full path.

That's caused the problem as the interpreter could not find the `encodings` package under the `Lib` folder.

Could you try to create a new one?